# aclocal: error: 'configure.ac' is required

Tags: linux, bash, configure, autogen

I am try to use .autogen.sh to build the files from this repository:
https://github.com/cnangel/pidgin-libqq

It works when I input the command (.autogen.sh) from the directory(**/project**) where everything is unzipped.

But when I want to build them from different directory (**/test**), it shows the error: **aclocal: error: 'configure.ac' is required**. I believe this is because when running autogen.sh in /project from /test directory, the autogen.sh still looks for configure.ac in /test directory.

How should I rewrite the **autogen.sh** file for it to recognize/scan the **configure.ac** file in the directory (**/project**) where they both located?

Appreciate any suggestion for this problem!

Comment: Your errors : You are supposed to run autogen.sh in pidgin-libqq/

Comment: Yes, I did. But it wasn't able to recognize the other files when I run it from other directory.